# Why do my PCI-e I/O register reads appear to be cached?

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I have a PCI-e hardware device that has a number of registers that I want to read from and write to.  However, when I read a register, I will get a value from a previous read (the first read returns 0xFFFFFFFF).

I'm using pci_iomap() to get the base address of the I/O area.  I tried using readl() and ioread32() instead of direct pointer dereferencing that was in the original code that I received.  All give the same results.

For example, if register `foo` contains 0xDEADBEEF, the first read will return 0xFFFFFFFF while subsequent reads return 0xDEADBEEF.  If I then read register `bar`, which contains 0xFEEDFACE, the first read will return 0xDEADBEEF, all subsequent reads will return 0xFEEDFACE.

Comment: That doesn't sound like normal caching. Also, I think that IO device accesses are normally always uncached, at least by default. Are you 100% sure the device behaves correctly?

Comment: Are you reading from the registers too quickly?  Some devices have slower chips on them so you can't read from them at full CPU speed, and have published minimum times between consecutive register reads.

Comment: You are reading from powered off device, presumably in D3cold.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ThomasJager.  It sure does seem like this is not normal caching, you're right.  Perhaps the device is buffering the value somewhere.  The hardware guy insists that he's not but I'll ask him to look again.  As you say, I/O operations ought to always be uncached.  Anything else would not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @1201ProgramAlarm.  In this case, it's simply a single register read that's triggered by a user action in a user-space program making an ioctl() call.  The application does not yet read more than one register at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @0andriy.  The device is definitely powered on as the register reads do catch up.

Comment: Exactly which PCI Express card are you using?  Manufacture, model, etc

Comment: How do you know? All symptoms, especially taking into consideration how you read register (from previous comment), look like you read too fast while device is becoming to be powered on. Cache issues look different.

Comment: It needs some investigation by your hardware guy. Normal PCI/PCIe devices shouldn't behave like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @user3629249.  It's a XILINX FPGA evaluation board that one of our hardware engineers has rigged up for the purpose.

Comment: I'll never be able to tell you much, since your hardware is not standard

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the bad values from the user code, calling ioctl(), and getting the bad value back, take a look at the driver's use of copy_from_user() and copy_to_user(). As a check you could use printk() or better dev_dbg() to print the register address and value as seen by the driver.

Comment: Thanks.  I am seeing the "stale" values in kernel space based on printk() calls to show the register values.